# Suppress display of "Text - Empty Text Node" in IE developer toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I'm getting tons of "Text - Empty Text Node" lines in IE's developer toolbar, on almost all the sites i dev. I don't mind their existence, but it makes it much harder to find code. Is there a way to hide "Text - Empty Text Node" from showing?

PS: This is the "F12 developer tools" inside IE9.

PPS: I'm NOT looking for a "rewrite your code to prevent 'Text - Empty Text Node' from appearing" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can not be done. Sorry. It is showing the true DOM tree, rather than how other developer tools simplify the result. Opera Dragonfly has an option to switch to a similar style, but F12 doesn’t have the reverse.

However, IE11 will have a new version of F12, which looks like it has the same, more simplified view: http://mcakins.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/internet-explorer-11-brings-massive-upgrade-to-f12-developer-tools/